# WaitForSingleObject and WaitForMultipleObjects equivalent in modern c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

The windows functions, CreateEvent, WaitForSingleObject and WaitForMultipleObjects are handy but only used in win32. Can I replace them using Modern C++ threading in a generic way?
I find a post, https://vorbrodt.blog/2019/02/08/event-objects/, to manually set and reset event in modern c++.  is there a better way to do that?

The below is the code snippet of old windows code:

```
DWORD TX_LAYER::__TX_THREAD(HANDLE *done)
{
   CONNECTIONS          *con    = nullptr;
   void                 *temp   = nullptr;
   const HANDLE h[] =
   {
    *doneEvent,
         evtTX
    };

   const DWORD num_evts = _countof(h);

   while ( true )
   {
       DWORD ret = -1;

      ret = WaitForMultipleObjects(num_evts, h, FALSE, INFINITE);

      // Stop signal or critical error.
      if ( (ret == 0) || (ret == WAIT_FAILED) )
          break;

      // TX the packet.
      EnterCriticalSection(&csTX);

      if ( _tx.empty() == true )
      {
          ResetEvent(evtTX);
          LeaveCriticalSection(&csTX);

          continue;
      }

      temp = *_tx.begin();
      _tx.erase(_tx.begin());

      if ( _tx.empty() == true )
          ResetEvent(evtTX);
      else
          SetEvent(evtTX);

      LeaveCriticalSection(&csTX);

    ....
    ....
    ....
      temp = nullptr;
   }
```

Comment: The way you are using it, [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) probably comes closest.